# How to get all celery tasks?

Tags: django, django-celery

everyone. I want to get all celery tasks in my program. 
Like Django-admin did.

[image]

But I have searched a lot which didn't help.
Plz. Help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this code would solve this problem:

```
from celery import current_app
def get_celery_all_tasks():
    current_app.loader.import_default_modules()
    tasks = list(sorted(name for name in current_app.tasks                         
             if not name.startswith('celery.')))
    return tasks
```

Then will return all celery tasks beside celery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do something such as this:

```
from celery import current_app

for name in sorted(current_app.tasks):
    if not name.startswith('celery.'):
        print(name)
```

`django-celery` [does something similar](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/0a1e83df7d5ae75ab0be958f600b55c892cf98b3/djcelery/admin.py#L256) to retrieve the list of tasks for the admin display.

Comment: Thanks . But i got not all tasks when i use this code.  It only contain the celery's own tasks. But acctually , I got a lot costom tasks, just like the pic before. Got any idea???
>>> tasks = list(sorted(name for name in current_app.tasks
...                             if not name.startswith('celery.')))

>>> print(tasks)
['NewCmdb.celery.debug_task']